# Как вам такие неологизмы?

Tags: лексика

Не совсем вопрос, просто поделиться. В комментариях  в "Одноклассниках" у разных людей увидела вот такие слова: псакинг, не псакингуйте. Как Вам такие неологизмы?

Comment: Псакинг - от фамилии известной американской чиновницы Псаки?

Comment: Думаю, да.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Считается, что неологизм является звеном в цепочке языковых новообразований: «потенциальное слово — окказионализм — неологизм».

Когда употребляют слово "псакинг"? Ответ: "Так говорят, когда человек, не разобравшись, делает безапелляционные заявления, при этом путая факты, без последующих извинений".

Следовательно, псакинг - это явление. Оно возникло в  политике, но в целом может быть применено и к другим областям жизни. Вернее, в языке есть потребность в слове, обозначающем такое понятие. Стадию окказионализма слово уже прошло и претендует на звание неологизма.

Однако большинство неологизмов существуют в языке короткое время, только некоторые закрепляются в нем. Не думаю, что жизнь этого термина будет долгой: слово излишне политизированное, чтобы обозначить явление в целом, а также не отличается благозвучностью.

Answer (score 5):

> Как Вам такие неологизмы?

Да так же, как и все неассимилированные заимствования. Лично я, хватаясь за перо, произвожу столь строгий отбор лексики, что иногда у меня в буквальном смысле нет слов, чтобы сформулировать мысль. Я даже таких единиц, как *страна*, *принц*, *рассказ*, избегаю, как попадания инородных тел в глаза, полагая их элементами лексикона младшей группы детского сада. Какой уж там *псакинг*, *топикстартер*, *пост*, *сабж*, *фикрайтер*... Помилуйте.

> Cледовательно, псакинг - это явление.

Явление. Но я уверена, что, описывая n-ное явление, нужно искать способы его описания -  лексическими ресурсами русского языка, будь оно хоть явлением Христа народу.

> Суффикс ИНГ в русском языке уже достаточно понятен и в данном случае более удобен для образования родственных слов: псакинговать, не псакингуйте.

Меня не устраивает такой сугубо утилитарный подход к речи. Я всегда уделяю внимание эстетическому аспекту любой формы самовыражения. И активно навязываю всем свою точку зрения.
Если имеет место *обломовщина*, можно сказать *не обломствуйте*. Но если приходится производить на свет божий богомерзкие слова, чтобы сформулировать мысль, - лучше отказаться от намерения сформулировать ее, используя такого рода произведения.
[[@Марк Из](/users/1067/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7)](/users/1067/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7), «отец» *псаковщины*, наглядно продемонстрировал, однако, что в таких жертвах в данном случае нет необходимости.

> Вы увидели здесь апологетов этого слова? Вроде бы никто его не защищает, никому оно не нравится, и вряд ли кто намерен его употреблять. Просто дается характеристика неологизма: возможное значение, продуктивность способа образования, прогнозы на будущее и т. д.

Если Вы увидели здесь изобличение апологетов, прошу прощения, что оскорбила Ваши чувства. На самом деле я всего лишь высказала свое мнение по поводу охарактеризованного неологизма и ему подобных, не окрашивая свои комментарии эмоционально.

Comment: Вы увидели здесь апологетов этого слова? Вроде бы  никто его  не защищает, никому оно не нравится, и вряд ли кто намерен его употреблять. Просто дается характеристика неологизма: возможное значение, продуктивность способа образования, прогнозы на будущее и т.д.

Comment: Уважаемая "Чернушка" ("Noir") :-), Вы опрометчиво проявляете на этом форуме любовь к богатству чистого русского языка, не загаженного американским словесным мусором. Так мне показалось. Это чревато попаданием под заморозку и удалением Ваших исследований и вопросов на эту тему. Просто, я этот опыт уже имею. Похоже, что в 21 веке понятия "свобода самовыражения" (даже в совершенно культурной и достойной форме) и "демократия" претерпевают метаморфозные изменения в свою уродливую противоположность. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Довольно странное слово. Слово уже есть, а единого значения ещё нет. Означает или стиль ведения американской дипломатии, или процесс когда человек тупит и говорит самому непонятные термины.

Вообще, суффикс -инг сейчас понятен и часто встречается в современных англоязычных заимствованиях, но этот суффикс ещё не до такой степени обжит, чтобы от него появлялись самостоятельные массовые русские слова (сомневаюсь, что это слово есть в английском). Т. е., если бы я в спонтанной речи решил образовать слово от фамилии Джен Псаки, то появилось бы какое-нибудь "псакство", "псаковщина" или "псакизм",  думаю у большинства русскоязычных получилось бы тоже самое. Появление формы на -инг было бы ещё возможным при положительном значении слова, в значении политический троллинг, но как раз подобного значения не обнаружил. Слово бы могло возникнуть в среде хорошо знающих английский язык людей, с антиамериканскими взглядами на политику. Не думаю, что подобная группа людей большая.

Всё это наталкивает меня на мысль, что слово было придумано каким-либо проправительственным пиар-агентством и пущено в массы, в том числе через [гостелеканалы ВГТРК](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XalNXKjGbEg), чем и объясняется некоторая популярность данного слова. Сомневаюсь, что данное выражение просуществует более пары лет.

Comment: Верно. Некоторые политические предпочтения обычно заканчиваются на -ИЗМ-, например: коммунизм, фашизм, либерализм, консерватизм, национал-социализм. Также на ИЗМ заканчиваются слова, обозначающие некоторые религии: деизм, буддизм, иудаизм. 

Вообще, я бы не стал употреблять слова, закачивающиеся на -ing- хотя бы потому, что засорение...

Comment: Суффикс ИНГ в русском языке уже достаточно понятен и в данном случае  более удобен для образования родственных слов: псакинговать, не псакингуйте.

Comment: @София, я не спорю, что суффикс -инг понятен, но не заимствованных слов, образованных с помощью этого суффикса я не встречал. А образование родственных слов происходит от корня, от корня и суффикса - это лишь частная форма, которая для слов-обобщений мало подходит. Вы можете привести хотя бы один пример как от слова с суффиксами -изм, -щин или -инг образовано новое слово? Такого не происходит как раз потому, что делать явление невозможно, т. е. слово "псакинговать" , если задуматься, попросту бессмысленно. Делать как Псаки - это по-русски *псакить* или *псакствовать*.

Comment: Псакинг  может иметь два значения: а)явление (псаковщина);  б) тип поведения. Псакинговать - это вести себя определенным образом. Другие примеры: маркетинговый.

Comment: @София, "маркетинг" не подойдёт, так как нет слова маркет. Во времена своего появления, слово вообще было целиковым заимствованием, и сомневаюсь, что суффикс -инг, там выделяют сейчас, по крайней мере в вики корень "маркетинг".

Ещё раз поясняю, что если я буду вести себя как Хлестаков, то мне могут сказать, чтоб я не хлестаковил или не хлестаковствовал, а у последователя марксизма взгляды будут марксистские.

Comment: "Не надо псакинговать" -  даже если значение корня неизвестно, понятно,что речь здесь идет о поведении.  Язык выбирает ту форму, которая ему более удобна. Суффикс ОВА - универсальный, одним из его значений является "проявлять признак, названный мотивирующим словом".

Comment: @София, я согласен, что язык выбирает наиболее удобную форму, поэтому слово "псакинговать" и невозможно. Слово исходя из морфемной структуры должно обозначать "*вести себя как поведение у Псаки*". Кстати, носители русского языка это понимают, и у глагола "псакить" (в кавычках) по Яндексу 156 упоминаний, а у "псакинговать" - всего 9. Тоже самое наблюдаем в словах 2012 года "кержаковинг-кержаковить".

Именно от "псакинг", в виду значения обобщения, слово может образоваться только приставочным способом.

Answer (score 5):

Я не люблю излишних заимствований, непонятных новых слов, когда то же самое можно сказать привычными и ясными словами. Но слово "псакинг" (не бейте больно!) мне понравилось, потому что во-первых, это не заимствование, хотя слово и образовано с помощью иноязычного -инг, во-вторых, оно образное. Кому при встрече с этим словом не вспомнится госпожа Псаки? И сразу станет понятен смысл слова. Я согласна с Софией, тоже думаю, что слово не будет жить долго. Но пока мы помним "замечательные" высказывания Псаки, это словечко поживет. Хотя прогнозы здесь сложно давать. После ответа Tagirix набрала слово в поисковике и, к удивлению, обнаружила немало статей и высказываний о слове, и упоминание о том, что даже была передача Киселева об этом слове и явлении.  И кроме слова "псакинг" и "псакинговать" увидела еще и "псакнуть". Так что нравится-не нравится, а слово живет.

---

Я недооценила "плодовитость" слова. Фраза, конечно, несерьезная (с форума автомобилистов, кажется), но все же:  "Считаю любые проявления **псакинга** на форуме должны быть немедленно подвержены **антипсакингу** с последующим забаниванием **псакингующих**.

Comment: По Яндексу 156 упоминаний слова "псакить" (в кавычках), а у "псакинговать" - всего 9. В виду значения обобщения у слова "псакинг", от него вряд ли возможны слова образованные не приставочным способом.

Answer (score 1):

Подобные "неологизмы" появляются каждую неделю. А через пару месяцев их вспоминают только на таких вот форумах... Как только из информационного пространства исчезнет "раздражитель", слово забудется.

Comment: Как Вы можете быть в этом уверены? Возможно, некоторые из них могут прижиться и стать очень даже распространёнными.

Comment: Это - "злободневный" неологизм. Я уже видел "гибель" подобных "интернет-мемов" и почти уверен, что его постигнет та же участь, что и "галстучника" в смысле "труса"

Answer (score 0):

И что же это значит? Я даже не смог найти эти слова на просторах рунета. Значит, эти лексемы не употребляются даже в интернете (не говорим об определённом кругу людей).

Возможно, это процессное существительное, образованное, как уже сказали, от американской чиновницы Псаки?

Comment: Я только сегодня увидела это слово. Но так как Вы утверждаете, что нет в Рунете такого слова, тоже набрала его в поисковике. И первые же заголовки - "Вести Недели : Псакинг как стиль американской дипломатии", "ПСАКИНГ: новое явление в американской политике", "Ни дня без «ПСАКИнга»". Ссылки не даю, это первые строчки по запросу в "Яндексе"